# How to sort database in sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sorting

How to sort database according to Priority level-high,medium,low and should display in list view in android.
When ever the data enter it should check priority and according to that it will arrange it.

Comment: You don't sort the db table itself. You sort the results of a query.

Answer (score 1):

You use an ORDER BY clause.  Assuming you're using integers for those values, it should just be ORDER BY priority DESC

Comment: I am new to android can u give me any example.

Comment: @user3607296 http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_order_by.htm

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to sort the table when you add a new row,you can use android built in **Loader** class to sort and display data in **listView**.

Try this..

```
CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, 
            URI, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            "priority" + " ASC"); 
    return loader;
```